# Select text within h4

Tags: jquery

How would i grab the text 'Peanut Brownie' when the button is pushed.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/peanutBrownie320x150.jpg" alt="afghan">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$12.00</h4>
            <h4>Peanut Brownie</h4>
            <p>One Dozen (12)</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=".col-md-8 addToCart">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried ...

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() 
 {
 alert( $(this).closest('h4').text() )
 });
```

and a few other tricks but just get an empty alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the closest `div` that has an `h4`, and then the last `h4` child of that div

```js
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() 
{
  alert( $(this).closest('div:has(h4)').children('h4:last-of-type').text() )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/peanutBrownie320x150.jpg" alt="afghan">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$12.00</h4>
            <h4>Peanut Brownie</h4>
            <p>One Dozen (12)</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=".col-md-8 addToCart">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`closest` doesn't select the closing matching element, it selects the closest matching *parent* element. The target element is sibling of the `div` parent element. You could code:

```
$("button").on( "click", function() {
    alert( $(this).closest('.row').prevAll('h4').first().text() )
});
```

Note that I have used `.first()` method for selecting the first `h4` element as `text` method returns textContent of all the selected elements.